# accessing service program procedures in SQL scripts

Tags: sql, function

I have a service program with a variety of exported procedures.   I created two SQL functions that are supposed to be able to call the procedures.  Both procedures are simple:  send in one parameter, get a single result back.   I can access the SQL functions when using STRSQL, but if I try the same SQL statement in SQL Scripts of ACS I get this message:
**Vendor Code: -204 Message: [SQL0204] SLBRSRV in *LIBL type *SRVPGM not found. Cause . . . . . :   SLBRSRV in *LIBL type *SRVPGM was not found. If the member name is *ALL, the table is not partitioned. If this is an ALTER TABLE statement and the type is *N, a constraint or partition was not found. If this is not an ALTER TABLE statement and the type is *N, a function, procedure, trigger or sequence object was not found. If a function was not found, SLBRSRV is the service program that contains the function.  The function will not be found unless the external name and usage name match exactly.  Examine the job log for a message that gives more details on which function name is being searched for and the name that did not match. Recovery  . . . :   Change the name and try the request again.  If the object is a node group, ensure that the DB2 Multisystem product is installed on your system and create a nodegroup with the CRTNODGRP CL command. If an external function was not found, be sure that the case of the EXTERNAL NAME on the CREATE FUNCTION statement exactly matches the case of the name exported by the service program.**

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This is on IBMi, connecting to a DB2 database.   It's something weird in IBM's ACS client since the same SQL logic works if I try it in their 'green screen' environment runing SQL there...